# Validate WTF Flask Form Input Values

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have the following form in my flask app. I'd like to ensure that the input value is actually an integer and also if the value entered in token > k here k can be some number it spits an error message to the screen. The IntegerField doesn't seem to enforce integer values, e.g., if the user enters 2.3 it passes that to my function which fails because it expects an integer.

Can this type of error message happen in the form or do I need to program that inside my flask app once the value is passed from the form to the server?

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    token = IntegerField('Token Size', [DataRequired()], default = 2)          
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

*EDIT*
Per the comment below, updating this with my revised Form and the route

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    token = IntegerField('Token Size', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=10, message='Something')], default = 2)
    ngram_method = SelectField('Method', [DataRequired()],
        choices=[('sliding', 'Sliding Window Method'),
                 ('adjacent', 'Adjacent Text Method')]) 
    rem_stop = BooleanField('Remove Stop Words', render_kw={'checked': True})
    rem_punc = BooleanField('Remove Punctuation', default = True)
    text2use = SelectField('Text To Use for Word Tree', [DataRequired()],
        choices=[('clean', 'Clean/Processed Text'),
                 ('original', 'Original Text String')])
    pivot_word = TextField('Pivot Word for Word Tree', [DataRequired()])                
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

And the route in which the form is used

```
@word_analyzer.route('/text', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def text_analysis():
    form = Form()
    result = '<table></table>' 
    ngrams = '<table></table>' 
    orig_text = '<table></table>' 
    text = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tmp_filename = tempfile.gettempdir()+'\\input.txt'
        if request.files:
            txt_upload = request.files.get('text_file')
            if txt_upload:
                f = request.files['text_file']
                f.save(tmp_filename)
        if os.path.exists(tmp_filename):
            file = open(tmp_filename, 'r', encoding="utf8") 
            theText = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
            theText = str(theText)
            token_size = form.token.data
            stops = form.rem_stop.data
            punc = form.rem_punc.data
            ngram_method = form.ngram_method.data
            text_result = text_analyzer(theText, token_size = token_size, remove_stop = stops, remove_punctuation = punc, method = ngram_method)
            result = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(text_result, orient='index', columns = ['Results'])[:-3].to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover', header = "true", justify = "center")
            ngrams = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(text_result['ngrams'], orient='index', columns = ['Frequency']).to_html(classes='table table-striped table-hover', header = "true", justify = "center")
            if form.pivot_word.data == None:
                top_word = json.dumps(text_result['Top Word'])
            else:
                top_word = json.dumps(form.pivot_word.data)
            if form.text2use.data == 'original':
                text = json.dumps(text_result['original_text'])
            else:
                text = json.dumps(text_result['clean_text'])
            if form.validate_on_submit():   
                return render_template('text.html', results = [result], ngrams = [ngrams], form = form, text=text, top_word = top_word) 
    return render_template('text.html', form = form, results = [result],ngrams = [ngrams], text=text, top_word='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NumberRange` validator from `wtforms.validators.NumberRange`. You can pass an optional Min and Max value along with the error message. More info [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators/#wtforms.validators.NumberRange)

**Update**

```
# Form Class
class Form(FlaskForm):
    token = FloatField('Token Size', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=10, message='Something')])

# Route
if form.validate_on_submit():
    print(form.name.data)
```

Here is an example that should work, make sure your form class field looks similar and also that in your route you use `form.validate_on_submit():`.

Comment: thanks, for some reason this code `token = IntegerField('Token Size', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=10, message='Something')], default = 2)' yields an error that `NameError: name 'NumberRange' is not defined`?

Comment: Arg, I wasn't importing NumberRange. Did that, but strangely, now using this code, it seems NumberRange is ignored? When I intentionally go outside the boundaries the code still runs

Comment: I've updated the answer, have a look. if it does not work, please update your question with the code implementation of the route.

Comment: Thank you. Updated original question with actual form and route. Ideally, if the value `token` is outside the min/max boundaries, an error message would print somewhere on screen in a meaningful way so the user knows what correction is needed.

Comment: You're processing the form data without validating it, as shown in the code snippet you should check if `form.validate_on_submit()` returns True. Which is where the validators are checked. If `form.validate_on_submit()` returns False, then use `form.errors` to return the error message.

Comment: Thanks. I actually has it right above the part that renders a template like this, but even when I exceed the value of 10 for the token input it still renders the form `if form.validate_on_submit():    
                return render_template('text.html', results = [result], ngrams = [ngrams], form = form, text=text, top_word = top_word) `

Comment: updated my original question above so the indentation shows how it was used

Comment: You should evaluate `form.validate_on_submit()` before you work with the form data. Where as you're performing this right at the end. Which means you've worked with `token_size = form.token.data`  prior to validating it.

Comment: Gotcha, but something else must be an issue. I'm doing like `if form.validate_on_submit(): print('Hello')' and sending hello out to the html. It never prints Hello, but if if I do `if True: print('hello')` hello is printed. I'm wondering if something in my form is wrong or in the way I'm using the validate_ is wrong? Not sure why it's not evaluating to True (or False) in my code at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214294/discussion-between-avizzzy-and-user350540).